# What is the difference between "primäre" and "sekundäre Personenbezeichnung"?

Tags: semantics

In my book, there is a differentiation of two types of *personenbezeichnung* made, it is categorized as *primär* and *sekundär*, however this is never explained further.

It's about semantics.

Examples:

> **Primär**: Mensch, Gast, Laie, Passagier, Insasse, Star, Flüchtling, Abkömmling, ...-ling

> **Sekundär**: Vormund, Figur, Person, Putzkraft, ...-kraft, ...-hilfe, Wesen, Mitglied, Opfer, Individuum, Geschöpf.

I do not understand the difference between them. I have looked up "primär" and "sekundär" in this context but I can't find more about it.
Note: It is in a professional publication by an educated author, so there is reason to understand this distinction.

Comment: I understand the idea but the examples make no sense.

Comment: @Janka They are from the book https://www.winter-verlag.de/en/news/ni12950c933c188aabffeafdf/Neuerscheinung_Studien_zum_genderneutralen_Maskulinum/
I've not changed any. Page 39.

Comment: I was about to ask: Could it be that the distinction is about which terms are  masculine in a primary sort of way? For a moment I thought: the ones in the first set have masculine gender, but all in the second set are feminine or neuter... WAIT except "Vormund". But still?

Comment: @Alazon That is probably the way in which it was intended.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the German language per se, but about (linguistic or philosophical?) concepts that are independent of a particular language.

Answer (score 1):

*Primärbegriff* and *Sekundärbegriff* are fundamental classifications for symbols in semantics. Here, those terms seem to be fenced in to symbols that denote persons.

Comment: What could be the reason for "Mitglied" being sekundär, while "Mensch" is primär?

Comment: You would need to read about the theory of semantic symbols  in human languages (the English term seems to be "primary and secondary symbols"). In principle, a primary symbol is the thing itself, very objectively without any influence of human perceiption, a secondary one is thats subjectively perceived with all possible assumptions not even in the term. Examples would be "man" as "male human" for a primary symbol, "teacher" primarily assumed to be a male teacher (even if it could be a female as well).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer!